# A full parameterized model

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, random-effects

I have a model like this:

```
fm<-lmer(V4 ~ V2 * V3 + (1 | V1), data = data)
```

I want to obtain the full parameterization of it, with random intercept and randon slope.
I can use this model?

```
fm<-lmer(V4 ~ V2 * V3 + (1 + V2 + V3 | V1), data = data)
```

Answer (score 1):

The most general model with group-wise (i.e. random) intercepts and slopes for `V2` and `V3` would be

```
lmer(V4 ~ V2 * V3 + (V2 * V3 | V1), data = data)
```

Taking into account that `V2 * V3` is short for `V2 + V3 + V2:V3` we can identify the following terms:

1. A fixed effect offset (from the implicit `1 +`)
2. A fixed effect slope for `V2`
3. A fixed effect slope for `V3`
4. A fixed effect interaction term between `V2` and `V3`
5. A random effect offset deviation for every level of `V1` (from the implicit `(1 + ... | V1)`
6. A random effect slope deviation for `V2` for every level of `V1`
7. A random effect slope deviation for `V3` for every level of `V1`
8. A random effect interaction term characterising the deviation from the fixed effect `V2`-`V3` interaction for every level of `V1`
9. All correlations between random effects

The Cross Validated post [R's `lmer` cheat sheet](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet) is a great resource for understanding the individual terms, and how to successively build the most general model.